# Visual Studio: Attaching to development server creates a new one

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Here is what happens:

1. I Click "View in browser" which starts up a new asp.net development server.
2. Go to Debug > Attach to Process, and select that dev server instance (it's the only one running)
3. Watch as a new development server starts up on a new port.

The debugger still attaches to the correct instance of the dev server, the new one just seems to be there for no reason. Maybe it's some setting I don't know about, but I don't know why it would be useful at all. I recently installed VS2010 but didn't use it for a little while. This *may* have started happening in VS2008 after that install (and it has always happened in 2010 since I started actually using it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's spawning a Cassini instance for every web app project in the solution.

[And this is a dupe, BTW ;  )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363/how-do-you-configure-vs2008-to-only-open-one-webserver-in-a-solution-with-multi#16390)

Comment: Thanks. If I knew what the cause was I probably could have found the dupe : )