# asp.net development server starting unintentionally

Tags: asp.net, cassini

Bad day at the code face.  I normally debug my web applications using a local copy of iis.  Today while testing that code I suffered a couple of stack overflows.  Following that visual studio failed to connect to iis to debug further.  After rebooting I was again able to debug my web projects against iis.  The annoying problem I have now is that the asp.net development server (Cassini) also starts up when I click start debugging.  Does anybody have any idea what could be causing the unwanted server start?  I've checked my app properties and use visual studio development server is not checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have other projects in the solution that are set to use the Development Server? If *any* of the projects have the setting, Visual Studio will start the Development Server just in case you debug into that project.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: @Sly, see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363/how-do-you-configure-vs2008-to-only-open-one-webserver-in-a-solution-with-multi#16390 (the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363/how-do-you-configure-vs2008-to-only-open-one-webserver-in-a-solution-with-multipl/1904499#1904499) is useful as well)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a clean  + build or Rebuild ?  Sounds like a setting has gone awry somewhere.

In the web project properties, try checking `Use Custom Webserver` and manually put the URL in the `Server Url` field.

And of course you could try shutting down VS, restarting your machine, resetting IIS and all those other workarounds for Microsoft product-related issues ;-)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Doing a clean and rebuild didn't sort the problem.  Also it's still the same after a reboot.  You may be right that a setting has gone awry somewhere.  A while back I stopped being able to debug by using the option "start external program" and am having to use the "start URL" to fire up the default web browser.  Also I'm already using "Use custom web server" as my server option as at the same point as above the "Use Local IIS Web server" option ceased to work.

Comment: It could be that something is incorrect in the `.csproj` file for your web app. I assume you've got all this code in some kind of source control system (;-) - might be worth comparing your current `.csproj` and `.sln` files with earlier versions from back when the problem hadn't arisen.

A more tedious, but more successful fix might be to create a new project and/or solution and manually 'Add Existing ...' code files to it and building a clean version.